# Anonymous users unable to view Office files from sharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, office-integration, office-online-server

We have a SharePoint Server 2016 farm and I've implemented Office Online Server.
On static pages we have urls like `<a href='/doclib/test.pdf'>view pdf</a>`. After i installed Office Online Server, anonymous users are getting login promt for Office files.

Document library and Documents permissions have anonymous access permission. Before the Office Online Server there was no problem like this. But now SharePoint asking authentication when they click the href.

i will use `href='/_layouts/15/WopiFrame.aspx?sourcedoc=/doclib/test.pdf'>` but there are hundreds of urls and web parts which calling pdfs like i mentioned.

Any help? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PDF files, when clicked on typically open in the browser by default, but with OOS configured PDFs are attempting to open in the OOS version of word.
You can setup something like this to allow anonymous users to access OOS: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/administration/configuration-for-office-online-server-authentication-with-external-users
A quicker fix might be to disable PDFs from opening in OOS, this should revert to opening in the browser like before.  Note if these files are Office files as well as PDFs this solution would not work, this will only work for PDFs.  This should get you started, you will just need to exclude PDF files: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/set-spwopibinding?view=sharepoint-server-ps